# IndexOutOfRangeException while running FFTPitchDetector

Tags: c#, fft, naudio

I'm facing some problems on implementing `FFTPitchDetector`. What I actually want to do is to get real-time frequency from guitar input, I not so sure how to use the functions in `FftPitchDetector.cs`. Any idea?

```
private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
{    
   if (waveWriter == null) return;

    byte[] buffer = e.Buffer;
    float[] floats = new float[buffer.Length];
    float sample32 = 0;
    int bytesRecorded = e.BytesRecorded;

    waveWriter.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRecorded);

    for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += 2)
    {
        short sample = (short)((buffer[index + 1] << 8) |
                                buffer[index + 0]);
        sample32 = sample / 32768f;
        sampleAggregator.Add(sample32);
    }

    floats = bytesToFloats(buffer);

    FftPitchDetector PitchDetect = new FftPitchDetector(sample32);
    PitchDetect.DetectPitch(floats, bytesRecorded);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}",sample32);
}

private static float[] bytesToFloats(byte[] bytes)
{
    float[] floats = new float[bytes.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
    {
        floats[i / 2] = bytes[i] | (bytes[i + 1] << 8);
    }

    return floats;
}
```

When I execute the code, there's an error `IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled` which points to the line

```
fftBuffer[n * 2] = buffer[n-inFrames] * window(n, frames);
```

in `fftPitchDetector.cs`. What is the problem in my code?

Is there any open source code of C# Guitar Tuner? I wish to outsource it into my project.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in either `fftBuffer[]` or `buffer[]` you are trying to access an index in the array which does not exist.

So if `fftBuffer[]` has 4 items and `n * 2` totals 6 then you're trying to access `fftBuffer[6]` which doesn't exist.

So basically you need to check how many items are in each array before trying to access their values.

You will need to place checks in your code, for example:

```
if ((n * 2) < fftBuffer.length && (n - inFrames) < buffer.length) {
    fftBuffer[n * 2] = buffer[n-inFrames] * window(n, frames);
}
```

You first ensure that the indexes you are about to use for each array is not greater then the number of items the array.

Comment: from the code above can you figure out the problems? I can't find which one is the problem :(